# How do I make two different ActiveResource models use two different connection objects?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, format, activeresource

Turns out the connection between ActiveResource models is shared.  So if you set the format in one model, it *does* stay different from the format in other models.  However, if you call the `.connection.format` method on two separate models, that format changes every time you set a new format.  So if `Profile` got loaded in second with the format `:json` then `.connection.format` for both models turns into `ActiveResource::Formats::JsonFormat`

My original question was completely different (I didn't fully understand what was going on) - you can look at the edit history to see the original version.  Hopefully I'll get more responses...

Proof:

```
class Location < ActiveResource::Base
  self.format = :xml
end

class Profile < ActiveResource::Base
  self.format = :json
end
```

Then in a `rails console`...

```
>> Location.format
=> ActiveResource::Formats::XmlFormat
>> Location.connection.format
=> ActiveResource::Formats::XmlFormat
```

So far so good... the `Location` model and it's connection have the correct format.

```
>> Profile.format
=> ActiveResource::Formats::JsonFormat
```

Looks normal, that's the format for `Profile` that I want.

```
>> Location.format
=> ActiveResource::Formats::XmlFormat
```

Ok... Location.format is still the same after having loaded the Profile model
**Note**: These models are lazy-loaded so their files and code aren't included until you attempt to call the class name.

```
>> Location.connection.format
=> ActiveResource::Formats::JsonFormat
```

And here the problem begins.  After we've made a call to the Profile model, it f'ed up the `Location.connection.format`

```
>> Profile.connection.format
=> ActiveResource::Formats::JsonFormat
```

The formats are *not* supposed to be the same.  This causes parsing to be completely broken when you make a call to something like Location.find(:all, :from => "/something.xml") - it attempts to parse the `xml` as `json`

I guess my question now is - how do I separate the two connections?  (Or otherwise resolve this issue)

Edit to add this test in the console:

```
>> Location.connection == Profile.connection
=> true
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This... feels like a bug.

I was looking at `ActiveResource` source code.  When you call the `format=` method in your ARes class it writes the format to `connection.format`.

The `connection` method in this context will grab `@@connection` if it's defined, otherwise it will call `superclass.connection`.  In our case `superclass` is `ActiveResource::Base`.  As you can guess, `@@connection` on the `Location` or `Profile` models is not defined.  It *will* get set if you call `self.site=` on your class, in which case the `self.format=` method will set the format on your class-specific version of the `connection` object.

In my case I have no reason to use a different site variable for the different ActiveResource models, just a different return format.  For this reason I was setting `ActiveResource::Base.site = "myresource.local"` in development (and the appropriate one in the production.rb env file too).

So my fix for this problem?

```
class Location < ActiveResource::Base
  self.site = self.site
  self.format = :xml
end
```

Yep, `self.site = self.site` forces the class to use it's own connection object.  Somehow I feel like `self.format =` should also...

Not gonna accept this answer quite yet because it feels like a hack and/or bug, but that's how I solved it for now and it *appears* to work.

Hopefully someone else has thoughts on this?  It doesn't seem like very many people use ActiveResource but we use it on a daily basis and I have run into this before.